Displaying contextual audit logs on specific screen like member's profile, activities, statements etc
I have an application similar to banking app where all the member's information is displayed grouped in different tabs on the top.
These tabs are profile, activities, transactions, statements etc.
I want to have the provision to view tab specific audit logs/views without having to switch screens.
One thing to note is, I have already put some details in a bottom panel that opens when I want to view details.
How and where should I provision audit view?

Hi, thanks for your contribution to UXSE. To understand your question better, it would be good to have some context about the design problem such as screenshots and also an explanation of what the audit view is/means.

What hinders you from opening a floating window to show them? Are we talking desktop application or web app here?
